# change volume up and down using touchDragged (libGDX)

Tags: java, libgdx

In this image [image] How can I use `touchDragged` to drag this [image] in `x` axis only ??

This is my code to make this action:

```
iBtnDrag = new Image(tBtnDrag);
iBtnDrag.addListener(new ClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void touchDragged(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer) {
            iBtnDrag.setPosition(x, 448, Align.center);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create DragListener

```
    ...

    float startX;

    DragListener listener = new DragListener()
    {
        public void dragStart(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
            startX = x;
        }

        public void drag(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
        {   
            //x, y are delta from starting point so
            iBtnDrag.setPosition(startX + x, 448, Align.center);
        }

        public void dragStop(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer)
        {
            //when stopping drag
        }
    };
```

---

**buuuut a way better would be to just create the [Slider](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Slider.html)**. To achieve it the best would be use [skin mechanism](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx)

your skin file should be like for example:

```
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Slider$SliderStyle: 
    {
        default-horizontal: { background: greenBackground, disabledBackground: sliderDisabled, knob: woodenKnob, disabledKnob: transparent },
    },
```

and then you are creating slider like

```
    music= new Slider(minValue, maxValue, stepSize, isVertical, skin);
    music.setWidth( musicSiderWidth );
```

Slider allows you to get its value by calling

```
    music.getValue();
```

which is actually very convenient

Comment: Ya, That's it. Slider is the perfect solution. Thanx @m.antkowicz